# Using both value and ngModel for an input field not working?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-forms

This concept is about user profile. I want to assign a value(userData.email_id) coming from api using **[value]** attribute of input and upon changes i want to get data back to TS  using **ngModel** into email_id property.

Here i am failing to assign value to input using [value]. Suggest me the solution.

**Note:** Here userData.email_id is coming from server.

TS:

```
 email_id: string;
```

html:

```
          <mat-form-field>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  placeholder="Email"
                  matInput
                  [(ngModel)]="email_id"
                  [value]="userData.email_id"
                  name="uEmail"                     
                />
              </mat-form-field>
```

Comment: remove ``[value]`` and set the value of ``email_id`` as ``userData.email_id``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could directly use **`[(ngModel)]`** and set the value to that, and get the changes via **`ngModelChange`** as follows , hence remove **`[value]`**

```
<mat-form-field>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  placeholder="Email"
                  matInput
                  [(ngModel)]="userData.email_id"
                  (ngModelChange)="sendData(userData)"
                  name="uEmail"                     
                />
</mat-form-field>
```

**EDIT**

If you do not want to handle this in each field, you could create a button to send all your changes to server by following way,

```
<button (click)="sendData(userData)"></button>
```

In this case you do not need **`ngModelChange`** on each input

Comment: But the problem is i have around 12 fields in my form ?? Have i to use sendData () method for each field? I want automatically reflect changes into my ts file.

Comment: you do not have to use each field you can just send userData which is an object contains 12 fields

Comment: wt exactly is the parameter userData inside sendData method?

Comment: userData is the object that you get from the server with the latest changes